# Unable to fetch data from phpMyadmin using data table

Tags: c#, wpf, phpmyadmin

I am creating a hotel management system, in which i am supposed to fetch the room for a specific reason. I am fetching `room_NO` from booking table using `tourist_CNIC` field from the same table. But i always get 0, instead of getting proper room number, which i have assigned to all of the rooms. Bellow is my code:

```
 private int Fetch_Room()
         {
             int number = 0;
             try
             {
                 String str = "SELECT room_NO FROM booking WHERE tourist_CNIC='" + cnic.Content.ToString() + "'";
                 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(str, con);
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 da.Fill(dt);
                 foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                     number = Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]);
                 return number;
             }
             catch (Exception x) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + x.Message); return number; }
         }
```

Comment: its suppose to be `row.ItemArray[0]` ?

Comment: Well it also doesnt work with ''row.ItemArray'' either @Mostafiz

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MySqlDataReader` for this case. try below solution

```
rivate int Fetch_Room()
        {
            int number = 0;
            try
            {
                String str = "SELECT room_NO FROM booking WHERE tourist_CNIC='" + cnic.Content.ToString() + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                  {
                     number = (int)rdr.GetValue(0);
                  }
                return number;
             }
           catch (Exception x) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + x.Message); return number; }
        }
```

Comment: This didn't help @Mostafiz